# Select does not working after SubmitChanges()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a WPF4 application i have 1 window which editing data :

```
main mn = db.mains.Single(p => p.ID == mID);
mn.Type = cbTypes.Text;
mn.Sum = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSum.Text);
mn.Datetime = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value;
mn.Reason = txtReason.Text;
db.SubmitChanges();
this.DialogResult = true;
this.Close();
```

after this closing window i have this:

```
if (ed.DialogResult)
{
    var dat = (from d in db.mains select d).ToList();
    this.GetData();
}
```

but dat is not filling with updated data(tried with debugger).
I tried same thing in edit window and its working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534217%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on the entities before you pull them down again:

```
if (ed.DialogResult)
{
    db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, db.mains);
    var dat = db.mains.ToList() // just use a lambda here, less code
    this.GetData();
}
```